# Enter 2 numbers by keyboard and display the largest/smallest and power class with Math ?

Tags: javascript

Here's the scenario: the user inputs two numbers in each box, and chooses from the  box Min, Max, and pow. Numbers are unlimited, which are entered by keyboard, it could be any integer, and the result should either be Max/Min/Pow. I already have my option box, and layout ready, but I cannot get my results as it either gives a 'NaN' or nothing at all.

Can someone please help in finding out the error in my code?

```js
<script>
  function calc(){
   var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
   var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
   var oper = document.getElementById('operators').value;

   if(oper === 'min')
   {
   document.getElementById('result').value = Math.min;
   }
  } 
 </script>
```

```html
<select id="operators">
 <option value="min">Math.min</option>
 <option value="max">Math.max</option>
 <option value="pow">Math.pow</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="num1" value="">

 <input type="text" id="num2" value=""> 
 <button onclick="calc();">Evaluate 2 input function</button>
 <br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide arguments to `Math.min()`

```
 document.getElementById('result').value =  Math.min(num1, num2)
```

See code snippet:

```js
function calc() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
  var oper = document.getElementById('operators').value;

  if (oper === 'min')
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = Math.min(num1, num2);
  else if (oper === 'max')
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = Math.max(num1, num2);
  else
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = Math.pow(num1, num2);
}
```

```html
<select id="operators">
  <option value="min">Math.min</option>
  <option value="max">Math.max</option>
  <option value="pow">Math.pow</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="num1" value="">

<input type="text" id="num2" value="">

<button onclick="calc();">Evaluate 2 input function</button>
<br><br>

<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it's not working, still not getting a result back :(

Comment: Try debugging in the browser? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Just tried the code you've edited it works perfectly! Thank you :)